# FBSDK not returning user's emails

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I've looked through all of the previous posts and cannot find a solution. I am connecting and it is returning everything except for the email. Is there some change with the most recent version that is now allowing me to receive that?

Here is the relevant code -

```
-(void)checkFacebookFriends {

[FBSDKAccessToken refreshCurrentAccessToken:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {


    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"user_friends"]) {

        [self makeFacebookFriendsRequest];
        // TODO: publish content.
    } else {

        FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
        [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_friends", @"public_profile"]
                            fromViewController:self
                                       handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                           //TODO: process error or result.

                                           if (error == nil) {
                                               [self makeFacebookFriendsRequest];
                                           }
                                           else {
                                               NSLog(@"no");

                                           }

                                       }];
    }
}];

}

-(void)makeFacebookFriendsRequest {

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/friends", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID]
                              parameters:@{@"fields": @"email,name,picture"}
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {


    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSDictionary *user in [result objectForKey:@"data"]) {
        FacebookUser *fbUser = [[FacebookUser alloc] initWithDictionary:user error:nil];
        [temp addObject:fbUser];

    }
//        self.facebookUsers = temp;

//        [self.tableView reloadData];

    // Handle the result
}];
}
```

Comment: Facebook allows registration through mobile number only as well. That's why you might not be getting the email address.

Comment: @BhavukJain I am testing with my team. They have registered emails normally, still not seeing it.

Comment: I think you can get the email address of the account you are logged in with but not of your friends.

Answer (score 0):

you will get the Email, name, id, birth date if you write the permission by using following lines of code.

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                                        parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, email, gender,picture,age_range,birthday"}]
                      startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError * error)
                      {
                          if (!error)
                          {
                              NSString *fbAccessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;
                              NSLog(@"the result is%@",result);


                          NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                          [prefs setObject:[result objectForKey:@"name"]   forKey:@"Facebook_NAME"];
                          [prefs setObject:[result objectForKey:@"email"]  forKey:@"Facebook_EMAIL"];
                          [prefs setObject:fbAccessToken forKey:@"Facebook_TOKEN"];
                          [prefs synchronize];

                      }
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

                      }

                  }];
```